# Image in scrollview doesn't display properly

Tags: android, android-xml, android-scrollview

I having a problem to display the image nicely at different devices.
Example of S3 Device, they displayed the way I wanted:
[image: S3]

However is S6 Device, the image display is too small especially for portrait images.
[image: S6]

Anyone got idea how to solve this issues because I tried to use weight , match parent etc doesn't really work on it. 
p.s. when i put my imageview above scrollview , sometime work quite perfectly.

Below is my current XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ivEventInfoPoster"
                    android:src="@drawable/carfreeday"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/common_img_desc"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvEventInfoTitle"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvEventInfoDesc"
                    android:text="Desc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvEventInfoDate"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your image view?

Comment: Do you have this drawable for different screen sizes, as the screen resolution of S3 is 720 x 1280 pixels and S6 is 2,560 x 1,440.

Comment: Yup, it's make my image lot of white space @NaviRamyle

Comment: @EricB. but the data from backend thus the image size are unpredictable.

Comment: Oh, then try giving it a fixed height, as you are working with a ScrollView and add  android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: @EricB. the ratio will have problem of using fitXY and the image size are unpredictable so I don't think it's was a good choice to do this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/ivEventInfoPoster"
  android:src="@drawable/carfreeday"
  android:scaleType="fitStart"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"                 
  android:contentDescription="@string/common_img_desc"
/>
```

Comment: adjustViewBounds not working inside Scrollview. It worms perfectly outside scrollview

Comment: @JithinAngel'zJas'z it should work, make sure you also have the `android:scaleType ` set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) of your ImageView?

Aside from scaleType, you may also set the [adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#adjustViewBounds) attribute of your ImageView